# How to setup a user with sysadmin rights on Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I started using Amazon RDS and I am trying to link two of my databases together but I don't have the appropriate permissions to do it. When I setup the database for the first time is only letting me setup a regular user without sysadmin rights. Is there anyway of getting sysadmin rights? Also, there is a user rdsa (with sysadmin rights) but I don't have access to it since is something that I guess amazon added to my RDS instance automatically on creation. Any thought on that?

Edit: I am running a MS SQL Server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because RDS is a managed service they limit what you are able to do with it. According to the [RDS documentation for MSSQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html) this includes the following restrictions:

> The following server-level roles are not currently available in Amazon
>   RDS:
>
> bulkadmin
>
> dbcreator
>
> diskadmin
>
> securityadmin
>
> serveradmin
>
> sysadmin

And also:

> Amazon RDS currently does not support the following SQL Server
>   features:
>
> ...
>
> Replication

Even if they did support replication for MSSQL it would likely be limited to replicating with other RDS instances.  With MySQL they only support replication between RDS instances, so if/when they support it with MSSQL it will likely have similar restrictions.

Comment: can you suggest a workaround for this issue then? I am trying to add data to my production database through a query which run on my development database.... any clues?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with MSSQL.  Can you do a backup and restore as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026990/best-easiest-way-to-make-a-sql-server-dump-and-import-that-dump-in-another-sql)?

Comment: You can use AWS DMS to do replication instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create a separate user with the appropriate permissions with a query. Similar question with answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/496966/amazon-rds-sql-server-master-user-privileges

Comment: this page says to create a `sysadmin` user. You can't do this on RDS.